# shell script to check if input is a string/integer/float

Tags: bash, scripts

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter value:" val

echo "$val"|grep "^[0-9]*$"
val="$?"

if [[ $val == 0 ]]
then
echo "Integer"
exit
fi

echo $val|grep "^[a-zA-Z]*$"

val="$?"

if [[ $val == 0 ]]
then
echo "String"
exit
fi


echo $val|grep "^[0-9]*.[0-9]*$"

val="$?"

if [[ $val == 0 ]]
then
echo "Float"
exit
fi
```

If I enter a string like "ape" it says "grep invalid range" and then prints float. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: What locale are you using? Please [edit] your question and include the output of `locale`.

Comment: +1 - you should probably also rethink re-using the same variable name (`val`) for the exit status that you use for the value to be tested. Also `==` is a lexical test (to test an integer exit status better to use `-eq` ). And remember that `.` means "any character" in a grep regular expression - if you want a literal decimal point, use `\.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This bash code returns integer for integers like 123, float for floating point numbers like 123.4 and string for any other input values like "123", One23 123. or 123.4.5.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Type a number or a string: " input
if [[ $input =~ ^[+-]?[0-9]+$ ]]; then
echo "Input is an integer."

elif [[ $input =~ ^[+-]?[0-9]+\.$ ]]; then
echo "Input is a string."

elif [[ $input =~ ^[+-]?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$ ]]; then
echo "Input is a float."

else
echo "Input is a string."
fi
```

Comment: "00001" is a string not an integer :+

Comment: This will also consider `+` or `-` (alone) as integers. Same for an empty string. And it will report `1.` as a float.

Comment: I fixed the `+` and `-` problem, but it still chokes on `1.`.

Comment: I edited it so it doesn't choke on 1. anymore.

Comment: Leading zeroes => octal.  `$ echo $(( 0009 * 2 ))` -> `bash: 0009: value too great for base (error token is "0009")`

Answer (score 4):

I can't reproduce your error, but since it's complaining about an invalid range, it's most likely a `locale` issue. Try running your script again, but setting the locale:

```
LC_ALL=C yourscript.sh
```

Of course, that won't fix the other problem which is:

```
echo $val|grep "^[a-zA-Z]*$"

val="$?"
```

After those lines, `$val` is no longer the value you gave, it is now the exit status of the `grep`, so everything after that is testing the wrong thing.

---

In any case, this is really needlessly complex. All you really need is:

```
#!/bin/bash

val="$@"

[[ -z $val ]] && echo "No input!" && exit

if [[ "$val" =~ ^[+-]?[0-9]+$ ]]; then
  echo "Number!" 
elif [[ $val =~ ^[+-]?[0-9]*\.[0-9]+$ ]]; then
  echo "Float!"
elif [[ $val =~ [0-9] ]]; then
  echo "Mixed, some numbers"
else
  echo "No numbers!"
fi
```

Note that I'm using `val="$@"` instead of `read`. This means you can now run your script as `yourscript.sh input` instead of having to type out the input every time. That way, you can see what you did in the history, you avoid typing errors, you can run the script automatically etc. It is generally a bad idea to use `read` and force your users to enter input.

Also note that I changed some of your terms. I now consider 4 possibilities:

1. The input has nothing but numbers: print "Number" (whether `001002` is an integer depends on what sort of maths you're thinking of).
2. The input consists of 0 or more numbers, then a dot and then nothing but numbers (0 or more because `.2` can be considered valid in some cases; if you don't want that, change the `^\d*\.\d+$` to `^\d+\.\d+$`).
3. The input has numbers but not *only* numbers: print "Mixed, some numbers". Note that this will also catch `1.` which is not a valid float and not a valid integer.
4. The input has no numbers: print "No numbers".

I split 3 and 4, but you can join them and have them print the same, if you like.

Also, kudos to Karel [for thinking of `+N` and `-N` numbers](https://askubuntu.com/a/1174143/85695).

Answer (score 1):

What about using the 'test' command side effect? Weighting a string suspect of being an integer, like `123`, with  e.g. `0` for equality returns `0` (true) or `1` (false) or `2` (error). This tells you directly whether string is worth comparing, i.e. if it is a valid integer representation:

```bsh
[ $str2test -eq 0 ] 2>/dev/null
if [ $? -lt 2 ]
  then
    \# Correct integer representation
    ...
  else
    \#Incorrect integer representation
    ...
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter value:" val

echo "$val"|grep "^[0-9]*$"
val="$?"

if [[ $val == 0 ]]
then
echo "Integer"
exit
fi

echo $latter|grep "^[a-zA-Z]*$"
latter="$?"

if [[ $latter == 0 ]]
then
echo "String"
exit
fi
```